# To search japanese sites in Google?

Tags: google-search, japanese

I am trying to search japanese sites for Embryology unsuccessfully by

> filetype:swf site:*.jp embryology

but it returns only a few results.

The problem is that I do not have specific url pattern in university sites.

**How can you search Japanese internet pages?**

Comment: Do you need to use filetype:swf? That will restrict the search to Shockwave Flash results. Eliminating that from the search string seems to return a lot more results.

Comment: I want to search animations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're searching an English term on primarily Japanese-language sites. Most *.jp sites will be written in Japanese, so you should search on Japanese terms (using Kanji/Kana, not Romaji).

Using Google translate, the Japanese word for "embryology" is "発生学".

- [Search for "発生学 site:*.jp filetype:swf"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E5%AD%A6%20site:*.jp#q=%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E5%AD%A6%20site:*.jp%20filetype:swf) gives 224 results
- [Search for "embryology site:*.jp filetype:swf"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E5%AD%A6%20site:*.jp#q=embryology%20site:*.jp%20filetype:swf) gives one result

Comment: The first search term is excellent! There was one very good search result. Thank you for that!